# Is there any Google api to search images.google.com?

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search, google-image-search

I've visited Google custom search engine. It seems it is for the sites included in the custom search engine. This is not what we want. So, I'm asking.

We need this api, even it is paid service.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer this question by myself.

No API to access Google images.